# CSRF authentication issue when using ionic as front-end + Devise-rails as backend?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, devise, ionic-framework

Is there any successful implementation that use Ionic mobile app to access remote Devise + rails Api server? Currently, the backend rails server works well, and I have added "rack-cors" to set white list for the remote access. On the front side, I use angular-devise to communicate with rails Api. But it shows the error below.

```
Can't verify CSRF token authenticity
Completed 422 Unprocessable Entity in 11ms
```

Most implementations use manually read token from csrf tag from rails or use 'angular_rails_csrf' gem. But all these above implementations rely on  rails. Is there any possible client-side implementation that only use angular, i.e. ionic app?

Answer (score 0):

Have you changed `:exception` to `:null_session` ?

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
  # For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
  protect_from_forgery with: :null_session
```

And also this information may be relevant to you.

[jwako/devise_token_auth_demo](https://github.com/jwako/devise_token_auth_demo)